# Repository pattern - Do I "need" a service layer in REST API?

Tags: rest, architecture, repository-pattern

*Im making this question to get your opinions on the matter, and to see if I'm being dumb or pedantic.*

---

## Question (tl;dr;)

Do I "need" the service layer (for good practice) when the repository layer already can do most of the things (like FindUserByID) with queries in a faster way, when the service has to do all these things manually in a much more inefficient and super manual way?

## Description (for those who want to read about my motives)

So, I've been dealing with Clean Architecture, which is great, but not for REST architecture. Since, Clean Architecture is literally made with a Controllers layer, and RPC is the one that handles controllers, not REST. REST handles resources. **So, I removed the "controller" layer, and I'm also thinking if I really need a "service" layer as well.**

So REST needs **"services"** and/or **"repositories"**. The strange thing, is that I think these two overlap. I know that **services** are supposed to **handle "business rules"**. But here's the thing:

### Repositories can do the same job with services, but repositories can do the **same job in a much more efficient way**.

Since Repositories are allowed to have direct communication with the database, they can use database queries (sql, or nosql ones). Which are much more **efficient to write**, much more **efficient to read**, much more **efficient on performance**.

#### Service way:

Say, you need to find a user by his ID, and then pick a specific friend from his friendlist by his name.

- You get all the users from **repository**
- You make a **loop** for all the users
- You make a **condition** where you check which user has the ID you want
- You make a **loop** for all his friends in the friendlist
- You make a **condition** to check the friend's name

**Summary? Like 20-30 lines of code and slower performance?**

#### Repository way:

```golang
filter := bson.M{
    "_id": id,
    "friendlist.name": friendsName,
}
projection := bson.M{
    "friendlist": 1
}
friend, err := mongoDb.find(filter, projection)
```

**Summary? Like 3-4 lines of code, and 99% database performance.**

So, is there any real need for the "Service layer" part? Is there any real architectural benefit on splitting it to a service layer and a repository layer, when repository can already do all the jobs much more efficiently by itself?

Comment: As is shown by your very first sentence, this question is opinion-based. As such, it is off topic.

Comment: I agree, but even opinion based matters can get best answers. I dont see how it's "off-topic", you can still give a pretty subjective answer to guide me and other people who may have the same question.

Comment: @Eksapsy It is off-topic if it is primarily opinion-based. That is, there is no way to give an authoritative answer.

Comment: It's not about giving your opinion, it's about giving guidance. You dont have to give your opinion if you dont want to. When someone asks you "What game-console to buy" you dont have to tell him "PS4". You can just ask him what his needs are, and thus making him reach his own conclusion without you having to give your own opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a small sample like "retrieve user by id", perhaps there is no need for a service layer.

However, in larger applications - things are way more complex. Some examples:

- The user store is broken out in a separate micro service, that needs to be queried for users over gRPC/HTTP.
- A cache layer is introduced to cache rest-resources (memcached, Redis, etc) that needs cache invalidation.
- The Rest-layer needs to be written into several versions with breaking changes, but the database is the same.
- You introduce an event bus to fire events when certain things happens in the system.
- You have extensive business logic that needs unit tests that does not rely on database connectivity.

Keeping things apart in layers will make it way easier to test, debug and make changes. If you experience bad performance from database queries, you can address that in the Repository layer by building better queries, with no concern over other parts. If there is a bug in the logic, you can fix it with no dependency of a database, simply build a unit test case and update the service layer and be done with it.

Layering is annoying for a one man show with a simple use case. It's a necessity for an app that's supposed to live for a long time with a lot of different customers and with multiple people working on it.

And I don't agree with your description of "the service way" vs "repository way". You should of course provide optimized methods in the repository for the service to use, essentially: Repository:GetSingleUserById should be there and be optimized in any case.

Comment: Alright, so the service layer's reason of existance is not to provide things that the Database can do anyway, neither to include business logic (since Database is better and more efficient at that as well as I demonstrated), but to provide logic like caching, calling seperate microservices etc. Am I getting this right? Just to make sure I'm 100% understanding this correctly. Your answer is ideal, very informative and subjective to the task, thanx for that.

Comment: Some business logic is very well executed close to/inside the database while other business logic is not. Especially when the data comes from multiple sources (other micro services, various APIs from other organisations, cache, etc..). Let's say you want to create a tax report from a number of financial transactions. I would query relevant transactions from the repo and do the calculations in the service layer.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I "need" the service layer (for good practice) when the repository layer already can do most of the things (like FindUserByID) with queries in a faster way, when the service has to do all these things manually in a much more inefficient and super manual way?

No, you don't.  Routing your data through unnecessary layers to score architecture points doesn't give you code that is easier to maintain, or cheaper to deliver.

See also Command Query Responsibility Segregation (CQRS).

Comment: By saying CQRS, are you indicating the possibility of just using repositories directly in controllers for reading and using services for mutations that needs some business logic?